# nuxt-img and js files cannot loaded on production mode on server

Tags: javascript, deployment, nuxt.js

I'm just learning Nuxt JS, and it's fine on my local computer until i want to try to deploy it on the server,
It's just a simple App, just Image and Text, but when i deploy it on the server the image won't load.
I'm using PM2 to deploy my App on my Ubuntu VPS

You guys can look at the error on https://bappedabjn.id as it look like this
[image]

EDIT :

I'm sorry i didn't include detail

Here is where i put the image at static/img/logo.png

[image]

And here how i called the image

```
<nuxt-img src="/img/logo.png" width="100" class="mb-10" />
```

And lastly here is my nginx.conf for @Lykos94 asking it

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

Comment: What is the path of the image? Please share some code.

Comment: Can you post the nginx.conf where you set the proxy_pass to the nuxt service?

Comment: @kissu i have updated my question and added some details.
Thanks for helping

Comment: @Lykos94 i have added the nginx.conf

Comment: I Don't know why, but suddenly the image loaded, and no error

Answer (score 3):

I tried to create a new NuxtJS project based on your information and added the `@nuxt/image` and I managed to reproduce your issue. You are currently using the `target: 'server'` (or none, and it's the default) option in your `nuxt.config.js`, which requires to have additional configuration for you to use the `@nuxt/image` module.

In particular you should follow the following guide at this [link](https://image.nuxtjs.org/providers/ipx/) and add this to your plugins:

```js
import { createIPX, createIPXMiddleware } from "ipx";

// https://github.com/unjs/ipx
const ipx = createIPX({
  dir: "static/", // absolute path to images dir
});

export default createIPXMiddleware(ipx);
```

After following the guide I managed to run the `npm run build` and run my server in production, displaying correctly the image.

Comment: Okay, i have solved the image problem, now what about the js files that's not loaded??